# UWP/Win2D - application crashes while loading canvas resources

Tags: uwp, win2d

I can't verify this for sure, but it appears as though my application is crashing because it's taking too long for my resources to load.

I believe it's coming from my call to CreateCanvasResourcesAsync

```
    public void OnCreateResources(CanvasControl sender, CanvasCreateResourcesEventArgs args)
    {
        args.TrackAsyncAction(CreateCanvasResourcesAsync(sender).AsAsyncAction());
    }

    private async Task CreateCanvasResourcesAsync(CanvasControl sender)
    {
        if (_tiles.Keys.Count > 0) return;
        await LoadImageAssets(sender, _tiles);
    }

    private async Task LoadImageAssets(CanvasControl canvas, IDictionary<int, CanvasBitmap> dictionary)
    {
        dictionary.Add((int)TileTypes.Tile1, await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(canvas, @"Assets/Tiles/Tile1.png"));
        dictionary.Add((int)TileTypes.Tile2, await CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync(canvas, @"Assets/Tiles/Tile2.png"));
    // etc.
    }
```

I am loading approximately 200 bitmaps, totalling roughly 4MB in size.

Has anybody else experienced this?  If so, did you come up with a workaround?

I have found some articles that offer suggestions at loading needed resources at runtime, but they don't seem to fit with the problem I'm having.

Comment: What does the implementation of `CreateCanvasResourcesAsync(...)` look like?

Comment: I've updated the description to include information on the methods being called by CreateCanvasResourceAnsync(...).

Comment: Is it possible to load the bitmaps externally and then pass them in to the view?  To verify that there were no issues with the images themselves, I loaded them externally to the view without issue.  If there is a way to inject the images into the view, it would be a good workaround.

Comment: Quick question, are you saying 4MB of JPEG/PNG data? Because once you load a JPEG or PNG into a bitmap, it's decompressed. Expect memory usage to be much higher than 4MB.

Comment: Yes, there about about 4MB of JPG/PNG data in the dictionary.  I wasn't aware there was a decompression of PNGs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem doesn't seem to be Win2D at all.  The problem seems to be that the dictionary is blowing up from trying to stuff in too much data.  I haven't empirically proven that, but I created two separate dictionaries, putting half the images in one and the other half into the second - and the problem was solved.

There is likely a better way to manage the dictionary to accommodate the full list, but this is a reasonable workaround for now.

Comment: 200 items in a Dictionary is not an issue. Are you saying you had to split your dictionary into two and have each one load 100 bitmaps?

Comment: Yes.  Splitting the images into 2 dictionaries fixed the issue.  I've got dictionaries that hold 100K+ rows without issue.  I was thinking it was the size of the data being stored in the dictionary.  However, I was loading the dictionary with all of the images externally without issue ... so I have no idea why it would fail using a single dictionary.